# Haskell and Visual Studio Code errors

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I started learning the Haskel programming language and decided to use Visual Studio Code.
I installed everything properly haskell and stack and a few haskell extensions in VS.
When I create a project and import Lib.hs into Main.hs the compiler throws out errors like it does not recognize the Lib module.
The code can be executed but errors in VS still show that they do not recognize the functions from the Lib module.

In the attachment I give some example and error in the picture.

Lib.hs :

```
module Lib where

data Expr = Val Int | Add Expr Expr
                    | Mult Expr Expr


expr :: Expr
expr = Add (Mult (Val 2) (Val 5)) (Val 6) 

eval :: Expr -> Int

eval (Val n) = n
eval (Add x y) = eval x + eval y
eval (Mult x y) = eval x * eval y
```

Main.hs :

```
module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main =  putStrLn $ "Result is :   " ++ show (eval expr)
```

Errors :

[image]

I know it’s a beginner’s problem, thanks for the help.
Of course any advice is welcome!

Comment: Maybe you need to work in `RecursionProj2` instead of the root directory (`WEEK 04`). I'm using the `Haskell` extension and it seems fine

Comment: BTW: there's no `show` instance for type `Expr`

Comment: @MeowcolmLaw Now that I have moved to folder `RecursionProj2` there are no errors, thanks. I'm wondering if you use Code Runner in VS, because when I try to run it, it doesn't work because of the same errors, but it works through the terminal?

Comment: I think you can’t use Code Runner in this case. As it’s a stack project, you can use the stack run command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`import Lib ()` means "don't import anything".

Remove the `()` part.

Comment: Nothing has changed, the mistakes are still there. It seems to be something up to a visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bug of the Haskell extension for VS-code of the Haskell publisher. Not solved yet in 2024 by the way.

I deactivated it also because it marks you mistakes even while digiting, it is distracting for me.

I use only "Haskell Syntax Highlighting", no debugger, and I compile from the VS-code terminal. I do not do huge projects, it is more than enough for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).